# Changing jQuery Mobile transition directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a web app, which I decided to use jQuery Mobile for it. The problem is my website is in Persian language which is a Right-to-Left language. I've created an rtl.css stylesheet which reverses everything, but I need to also reverse default slide transitions, meaning that it should slide from left to right and when adding data-reverse or back button it should slide right to left.

Can you please help me with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can check the [documentation here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/methods.html).

In your case, you should put this :

```
$.mobile.changePage( "nextPage.html", {
    transition: "slide",
    reverse: true
});
```

There is [another method](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4/docs/pages/docs-transitions.html): 
You can use the `data-direction` attribute in the link.

Exemple :

```
<a href="nextPage.html" data-transition="slide", data-direction: "reverse">Next page</a>
```

I think that you can set it globally in that way : you can find the following statement in the jQuery Mobile JS :

```
a.mobile.changePage.defaults
```

At that line, you can change `reverse:false` to `reverse:true`.

Comment: Thanks, but Isn't there a way to globally reverse everything?

Comment: Edit: direction: "reverse" change to data-direction="reverse"

Answer (score 14):

For markup, this seems to provide for a better slide effect and also more in-line with what jQuery Mobile does in their docs.

```
<a href="#main" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct syntax. The accepted answer needs to be edited.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is a Global option but you could iterate through all the page and add the attribute

```
data-direction="reverse"
```

jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

but @Zakaria is also a valid response